# Pragmatically setting value in a combobox embedded in a datagrdview

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to select a cell value in a combobox that is embedded in a datagridview programmatically. I have a datatable that has data pairs. I am comparing one column in the data table to the column in the datagridview and if they match I am trying to select the value in the datagridview combobox that matches.  I am not getting any errors, but I do not visually see the value on the form after it is set. Here is the basic code:

```vb
    Dim DA As New iDB2DataAdapter(strsql, Connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim i, j As Integer

    DA.Fill(dt)
    For j = 0 To dgvFields.Rows.Count - 1
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count = -1
            If dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(1) Then
                dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(2)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```

I have set a few watches for the dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells(0).value as well as the dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value and they are showing me what I would exspect, but visually the value is not showing in the comboboxes.

Is there something else I need to set that I am missing?

Comment: You have a type on this line: For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count = -1. Should the = be there?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using the name of the columns rather than the ordinal value of the column. While that worked I am not sure why, either approach should have worked.

This did not work:

```vb
dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(2)
```

This did work:

```vb
dgvFields.Rows(j).Cells("FieldName").Value = dt.Rows(i).Item(2)
```